# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning happening on Javascript database test

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, promise, async-await

this is my second post here!
OK so here's what happening, I'm learning MongoDB & more stuff about Javascript and me & my helper are completly stumped here.
I'm making an API for "Characters" and I'm checking if all the ID given to the array "installments" exists.
Thing is, it keeps adding to the database while saying the following message:

```
(node:3788) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Installment inexistant!
(node:3788) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside o
f an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the n
ode process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli
.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 4)
(node:3788) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections tha
t are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:3788) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Installment inexistant!
(node:3788) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside o
f an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the n
ode process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli
.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 7)
```

Here's what I did, I tried to try/catch it but it immediately gave the error...

```
/Checks if each installment of the tab exists
    check('installments').custom(tab => {
        tab.forEach( async (value) => { //For each value inside the tab
            const installment = await Installment.findById(value) //Try to find the value
                .exec()
                .then(myInstallment => {
                    if (myInstallment === null) { //If it doesn't exist, return an error
                         return Promise.reject('Installment inexistant!');
                    }
                });
        });
        return true; //If all exist, it's all good!
    }),
```

I hope anyone can find anything, I'll take anything I can because I'm very confused and the answers I find on StackOverflow don't seem to apply for this particular case (that or I just don't understand it...) Thank you so much for reading this! If that helps, here's the full "Create" function as well:

```
//Create
router.post('/add',
    body('name').not().isEmpty().withMessage('Le nom ne peut être vide'),
    body('installments').not().isEmpty().withMessage('Le personnage ne peut être relié a aucun jeu'),
    check('name').custom(async value => {
        const character = await Character.find({name: value}).exec();
        if (character.length !== 0) {
            return Promise.reject('Le nom existe déjà');
        }
        return true;
    }),
    //Checks if each installment of the tab exists
    check('installments').custom(tab => {
        tab.forEach( async (value) => { //For each value inside the tab
            const installment = await Installment.findById(value) //Try to find the value
                .exec()
                .then(myInstallment => {
                    if (myInstallment === null) { //If it doesn't exist, return an error
                         return Promise.reject('Installment inexistant!');
                    }
                });
        });
        return true; //If all exist, it's all good!
    }),
    async(req,res,next) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            res.status(400).send({
                errors: errors.array()
            });
            return;
        }

    const monChar = new Character();
    monChar.name = req.body.name;
    monChar.description = req.body.description;
    monChar.installments = req.body.installments;
    monChar.image = req.body.image;
    await monChar.save();
    res.send(monChar);
});
```

All the other stuff works well btw! I have my models and all that ^^

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve. You are rejecting a Promise and never handling the failure. You can add a `.catch(...)`  at the end, so your Promise rejection will not be unhandled but I assume you want to handle it somehow.

Comment: It looks like you are using `async/await` the wrong way. The result of the `async` function is never awaited, so the `await` inside has no effect. `await` will not block. It just wraps everything that follows in a promise and returns it. All the checks for the tabs run in parallel.

Comment: I just want to return an error if any of the installments in the array don't exist and cancel the creation of a new character.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So, does it mean it actually doesn't do the async/await and that it ignores my check?

Comment: what is the check function? what library is this?

Comment: if (myInstallment === null) { //If it doesn't exist, return an error
                         return Promise.reject('Installment inexistant!');}
Also, this is javascript MongoDb on PhpStorm

Comment: where is `check()` defined? what is `router`? which framework are you using?

Comment: does the 'name' check work?

Comment: Oh, check is const {check} = require("express-validator"); on top of the code alongside router being var router = express.Router();
Also I believe it's Express/Mongoose?

Comment: And yes the 'name' check does work, that's the only check that doesnt work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are doing exactly. However, if it works for the `'name'` check and the `custom` method can handle promises properly, then this might work (I further assume `tab` is an array):

```
check('installments').custom(tab => {
    const tabPromises = tab.map(value => { //For each value inside the tab
        return Installment.findById(value) //Try to find the value
            .exec()
            .then(myInstallment => {
                if (myInstallment === null) { //If it doesn't exist, return an error
                     return Promise.reject('Installment inexistant!');
                }
            });
    });
    return Promise.all(tabPromises).then(() => true);
}),
```

So all tab entries are checked individually and wrapped in a promise.  `Promise.all` waits for all of them to complete and returns another promise that fails when one of the tab promises fails.

Comment: Oh man thank you so much, it worked perfectly! I just had to change val tabPromises to const tabPromises but other than that it's perfect! Thank you and I understand Promise way better now! I had no idea you could use it without an await/async function
(Also, I've put a +1 on your answer but it won't count as I'm lower than level 15 on the reputation score but thank you so much again, I've put it as the answer of my problem!)

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry for the `val`, usually programming in Scala so this slips in often instead of `var`. I already noticed and fixed it, but apparently a bit too late ;-)

Comment: Haha that's fair I just filled the blanks myself anyway! ^^ Thanks for editing it for future readers though!